# Returning a cell's contents based on date and checkboxes in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of names starting in B6 and continuing down the column.  In cells E2:AG2, I have dates for attendance purposed.  For example, E2 is 2/26, F2 is 2/27, G2 is 2/28 and so on.  Columns E thru Columns AG are populated with checkboxes so I can find the name in Column B, match it with the date in E2:AG2, and go down that column to check the checkbox when that person is not here. I do that manually. Hope that makes sense.

Once I take attendance manually as described above, I want to create a formula that will find today's date in E2:AG2, look down that specific column looking for checkboxes that have been checked and return those names to me the name in Column B.  I am totally stuck.  Any ideas? Thank you.

I have tried using QUERY command and vlookup but have had no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=filter(B6:B,filter(E6:AG,E2:AG2=today()))
```

*Incase you wish to use the formula in a different tab & the source_date tab name is `Attendance`:*

```js
=filter(Attendance!B6:B,filter(Attendance!E6:AG,Attendance!E2:AG2=today()))
```

`logic`:

- *In the initial step of the formula, `filter(E6:AG,E2:AG2=today())` filters that specific column which matches with today's date listed in ***E2:AG2*** header*
- *Next I am saying whichever cells are tick-marked in the column we obtained in step_1, list out the associated names available in **B6:B***

Comment: It worked! That seems so simple, I can't believe I couldn't figure it out.  Would you mind explaining why it works? I would love to learn this so I can use it again in the future.  Thank you.

Comment: basic logic of the formula added to the answer section

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, I am just unsure of one part.  I understand step 1: filter(E6:AG,E2:AG2=today())  find the entire column that matches the date above it. I don't see where it checks to see if a checkbox is checked or not, I do see the part where it is returned b6:b.

Comment: I mean we can also specify it as `=filter(B6:B,filter(E6:AG,E2:AG2=today())=TRUE)` for clarity but here in this specific scenario since we are only dealing with TRUE/FALSE logic of checkboxes the formula automatically picks the TRUE ones even if it is not explicitly mentioned per se.,